# How to get the averages of each row unless they do not have a specific thing in row in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, average

[image]

I want to find the average percentage of each row. I do not want the average of the row that has "NA". How would i go about doing this.

Comment: Check out averageif(). Or iferror().

Comment: What about yellow highlighted columns?

Comment: Read up on the AVERAGEIF() function. Pay particular attention to how that function deals with #NA errors and values in the evaluated range that are not numeric. Based on the knowledge you gain from that study you will be able to decide whether to use AVERAGEIFS(), which allows multiple conditions, or simply use an IF function that prevents the AVERAGEIF from being applied if "NA" is present.